# Asp.net slidingExpiration not working with manually created cookie

Tags: asp.net

Manual creation of ticket:

```
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                1,
                username,
                DateTime.Now,
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes),
                false,
                "no,data",
                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
            );
var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
            {
                HttpOnly = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
                Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
                Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain
            };

HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
```

Web.Config file:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/LogOn"
       name="ticket"
       timeout="1"
       slidingExpiration="true"
       path="/" />
```

The ticket creation happens in a method in a ASP.NET Web API and the client is an iPhone communicating with the REST API.

Thanks!